# Unix Case RegEx

Tags: shell, regular-expression, wildcards

I am trying to match the date pattern using `case` command but it's not working. Can someone help me ?

**Input**: `01/05/1900`  or `5/6/1900`

Case statement used:

```
ptn="[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

case "$dt" in 
    $ptn ) echo "valid pattern" ;;
    *) echo "invalid"
esac
```

But the pattern used in the case statement is not evaluating for the above 2 date inputs.

Comment: You might be better off using `awk` rather than trying to do fancy pattern matching with shell globs.

Comment: Does BRE not have quantifiers? you know, so you can say `[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  `case` only understands globs, so a handling a regexp isn't straightforward.  The `=~` operator offers some solutions here though.

```
#!/bin/bash
INP="01/05/1900"
ptn="^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])/([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])/([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$"
if [[ $INP =~ $ptn ]] ; then
    echo valid pattern
else
    echo invalid
fi
```

If you fancy reducing the size of the regexp, `^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$` works equally well too.

Comment: Although, that regex is smaller, it still suffers from bad dates. Something like `(?:[0-2]?[0-9]|3[01])/(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])/[0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{2})?` would be a bit more correct. That means that `99/99/9999` is invalid, while yours says it is valid. Also, mine allows bizarre things like `31/02/2017`. But has some basic validation. You can play with it on https://regex101.com/r/zZ1mV7/1

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel If you care about invalid dates and you want to treat them exactly the same as non-dates, sure, but that is rare in my experience. If you don't care about invalid dates (because you know you don't have any), you can take the simpler matcher. If you want to display a proper message specifically about the date being invalid, you need to use the simpler matcher, at least at first, to detect it as a date at all.

Comment: @hvd And the point is...?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That's exactly what I was thinking... If when comparing the simple and the complicated pattern, the only benefit of the complicated one is that it addresses a non-issue, there's no point in going for the complicated pattern.

Comment: @hvd You're right, it doesn't address the "core" of the question, but an unasked issue. I am assuming the input isn't in a regular format, therefore, I wrote the tighter regex.

Answer (score 4):

As @Steve already [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310653/22222), `case` needs a glob, not a regular expression. You can still use `case`, you just need to give it globs instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
dt="$1";
ptn1="[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"           ## N/N/NNNN
ptn2="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"      ## NN/N/NNNN
ptn3="[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"      ## N/NN/NNNN
ptn4="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ## NN/NN/NNNN

case "$dt" in 
    $ptn1|$pt2|$pt3|$pt4 ) echo "$dt : valid pattern" ;;
    *) echo "$dt : invalid" ;;
esac
```

Then, run the script like this:

```
foo.sh 15/6/1900
```

For example:

```
$ for i in 05/6/1900 5/06/1900 05/06/1900 05/06/19 123/123/123; do foo.sh $i; done
05/6/1900 : valid pattern
5/06/1900 : valid pattern
05/06/1900 : valid pattern
05/06/19 : invalid
123/123/123 : invalid
```

If you have access to GNU tools (specifically, GNU `date`), you can also use a trick like:

```
#!/bin/sh
dt="$1";
date -d $dt &> /dev/null &&
        echo "$dt : Valid pattern" ||
                echo "$dt :Invalid pattern"
```

Then, on the same test input as before:

```
$ for i in 05/6/1900 5/06/1900 05/06/1900 05/06/19 123/123/123; do foo.sh $i; done
05/6/1900 : Valid pattern
5/06/1900 : Valid pattern
05/06/1900 : Valid pattern
05/06/19 : Valid pattern
123/123/123 :Invalid pattern
```

As you can see, this way you can get more valid patterns even for cases where, for example, the year is given as `YY` instead of `YYYY`.

Comment: Could prefer `$ptn1|$ptn2|$ptn3|$ptn4) echo …`

Comment: @Costas yes indeed. Answer edited, thanks.

Comment: Can you help me understand further... if case cannot understand RegEx, then how [0-9] is evaluated which is also a RegEx pattern in your code?

Comment: GNU `date` will accept completely unexpected patterns, e.g. `11:53`.

Comment: @Ruslan ah, true,  fair point.

Answer (score 3):

The "pattern" you present:

```
ptn="[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

#### Basic pattern

Will not work in a basic pattern as used by case. Basic patterns do not allow `|`. Nor allow the use of counts `{a,b}` (called "bound" in man 7 regex). To make it work in a `case` statement you need to explicitly build each pattern:

```
ptn1="[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]"                       # n  / n  / nn
ptn2="[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"             # n  / n  / nnnn
ptn3="[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]"                  # n  / nn / nn
ptn4="[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"        # n  / nn / nnnn
ptn5="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]"                  # nn / n  / nn
ptn6="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"        # nn / n  / nnnn
ptn7="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]"             # nn / nn / nn
ptn8="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"   # nn / nn / nnnn
```

And then use it as this:

```
case $dt in 
    $ptn1|$ptn2|$ptn3|$ptn4|$ptn5|$ptn6|$ptn7|$ptn8 )
        echo "$dt : valid pattern" ;;
    *)  
        echo "$dt : invalid" ;;
esac
```

---

#### (shell) Extended pattern.

Some shells allow the use of extended patterns.
Called pattern-list in ksh and Extended pattern (extglob) in bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
ptn="{2}({1,2}([0-9])/){2,4}([0-9])" 
while read dt; do
    printf 'line tested %20s ' "$dt"
    [[ $dt == $ptn ]] && echo "valid pattern" ||  echo "invalid"
done <"infile"
```

---

#### Regex

But the pattern you present could be reduced to this simpler (BRE) regex:

```
([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{2,4}
```

Which is:

- one or two digits followed by an `/`:    [0-9]{1,2}/
- repeat the above twice:                  ( ){2}
- append from two to four digits:          [0-9]{2,4}

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# also works in ksh and zsh.
reg="^([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{2,4}$"

while read dt; do
    printf 'line tested %20s ' "$dt"
    [[ $dt =~ $reg ]] && echo "valid pattern" ||  echo "invalid"
done <"infile"
```

---

#### BRE regex.

If you can not use ksh, bash or zsh, then backquote the regex:

```sh
reg="^\([0-9]\{1,2\}/\)\{2\}[0-9]\{2,4\}$"
```

And use `expr` (for example, sed and awk also may be used):

```sh
reg="^\([0-9]\{1,2\}/\)\{2\}[0-9]\{2,4\}$"

while read dt; do
    printf 'line tested %20s ' "$dt"
    expr "$dt" : "\($reg\)" >/dev/null && echo "valid pattern" ||  echo "invalid"
done <"infile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like terdon answer.

Regarding the **Regex** part of this question, your pattern is not valid.
you should escape with a `\` all special chars, like this:

`([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])\/([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])`

For known data sets like dates, don't try to reinvent the wheel since there are literally thousands of answers on the internet for matching dates. 
If you want to create anything more personal, use regex helpers like my personal favorite [regex.com](http://www.regexr.com/) to test and enhance your pattern as you wish.

**Edited:** With escaped chars, your code will catch some dates, but still it isn't perfect, because it will never catch `01/01/2016`, instead it will catch only `01/01/20`. The "priority" is 2 numbers for year, instead of 4.
You need to switch them to find first the biggest match and if that fails, it will catch the smallest one:

`([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])\/([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9])`